# Include behaviour inside ng-switch

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a reasonably non-trivial Angular-js application for the first time and am trying to establish some intuition about how to get things done. Most things are making sense, but there's one pattern in particular that has me stumped -

Whenever I place an "include" style directive inside an ng-switch, it is ignored. I've experimented with just about every style of ng-switch, ng-include, and ng-transclude I can think of to achieve the desired behaviour, but to no avail. I haven't noticed any documentation indicating that this would be disallowed, nor any equivalent style of pattern.

Here is an example of what I have tried to do:

```
<div ng-switch="is_logged_in()">
    <div ng-switch-when="true">
        logged-in:
        <div ng-include="'views/logout.html'"> </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
        not-logged-in
    </div>
</div>
```

The expected behaviour being that the logout form is displayed when `$scope.is_logged_in()` returns true.

The behaviour I see is that "logged-in:" is displayed, but the include isn't.

I've tried various versions of Angular-js. I've inspected the network traffic and seen that the include is in-fact being fetched, but I can't get this to work. I've had the same behaviour manifest when trying to build my own template control structures using directives.

The way I've seen most examples dodge this is by using JS in a directive to manually show/hide various sections of the transcluded content - is this really the idiomatic way to get the behaviour I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to repo the behaviour in a fiddle. You may yourself find the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how to load an external view in a fiddle. There are CORS issues. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

While using ng-include I always assign the path to a variable in controller.

```
$scope.logoutlink ='views/logout.html'
```

And in the view you can assign as

```
<div ng-include="{{logoutlink}}"> </div>
```

It would be helpful to post a JSfiddle link.

Comment: I'll give that a go, although I would find it surprising if a literal string expression didn't work, but this did.